# When I use Delete query the data will be deleted but it's show until reload page

Tags: php, mysql

### When I use Delete query the data will be deleted but it's show until reload page.
if this is default system
then
I want to that when i execute delete query the page(self page ) will be automatically reload,
or,

```
  public function delete($query){
    $delete_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
    if($delete_row){
        return "Data Delete Succes";
        
        exit();
    } else {
        die("Error :(".$this->link->errno.")".$this->link->error);
    }
  }



    if(isset($_GET['status'])){
        if($_GET['status'] == 'delete'){

            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $deleteUserQuery = "DELETE FROM `admin_info` WHERE id= $id";
             $result = $crud->delete($deleteUserQuery);
             if(isset($result)){
              
                 echo $result;
             }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to reload your page in success of delete query. automatic reload is not written in your code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements when your SQL statement includes input coming from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by default unless you write a simple code block to automatically refresh the page once the query has executed successfully. You can do this in many ways using php, js etc...

If you are using php, try adding the code block below and change the url to the page name you want the site to redirect

```
header("Location: url");
```

Refer the PHP Documentation on the usage of this `header` element here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Or use AJAX

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, i have already try this but got this warning 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\PHP\htdocs\PHP\IDB Project\SMS_APPLICATION\admin\includes\nav.php:1) in D:\PHP\htdocs\PHP\IDB Project\SMS_APPLICATION\admin\views\admin-user-all.php on line 14

Comment: @IslamYearul Add the code `ob_start();` at the very top of all your php code